# How to access html elements on .html() using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is where I want to add the html

```
 <div id="people">
```

This is my script and when the button is clicked its text will be change

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "response1.php",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(JSONObject) {
   var peopleHTML = "";

  // Loop through Object and create peopleHTML
  for (var key in JSONObject) {
    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        peopleHTML += "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3'   
   style='padding-top:10px;'>";
  peopleHTML += "<div class='box'>";
   peopleHTML += "<div class='row'>";
    peopleHTML += "<h3>" + JSONObject[key]["name"] + "</h3>";
    peopleHTML += "<div class='col-xs-12'>";
    peopleHTML += "<p>"+JSONObject[key]["gender"]+"</p>";   
    peopleHTML += "</div>";
    peopleHTML += "<button class='btn btn-primary' id='cris'>
   CLICK ME</button>";
    peopleHTML += "</div>";
    peopleHTML += "</div>";
    peopleHTML += "</div>";        }
  }

  // Replace table’s tbody html with peopleHTML

  $("#people").append(peopleHTML);

 $('#cris').click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).text('I CHANGE');
});
}
});

});
 </script>
```

How can I access the html elements I added so that the click function will work? I also used json to get my data's on database.

Comment: `$('#cris').click(...)` will work just fine. The issue may be that `event` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

If the `.on()` method is not working, you can try with this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#cris', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('I CHANGE');
});
```

This method should work no matter what, but using `body` is not the best option anyway: you are telling jquery to add a listener to the whole `body`... It would be better to use a narrower parent, like

```
$('.chrisparent').on('click', '#cris', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('I CHANGE');
});
```

edit: here's the working code (without the ajax call): https://jsfiddle.net/a34poca9/

Comment: `event` appear `undefined` at handler of either alternative ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the event parameter to the function... I've edited my answer.

Comment: What's wrong with what the OP is using? `$('#cris').click(function(){ ... });`

Comment: If it was just an `undefined event` problem then there is nothing wrong with his code, he was just missing to pass it as a parameter. If there is something more than what we can see in this post, then the event delegation approach has solved many problems to me.

Comment: @ToX82: But blindly applying event delegation isn't a good approach either. The OP binds the event handler *after* the new content was added to the document, so using event delegation is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`event` not defined as parameter within `click` handler anonymous function ?

```
$('#cris').click(function() {
  // `event` is `undefined` here
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).text('I CHANGE');
});
```

, which would return error when reach `event.preventDefault()` ?  Try adding `event` to `click` handler

```
$('#cris').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).text('I CHANGE');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use delegation for this. Code like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cris', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).text('I CHANGE');
});
```

This will capture the click event on any element with the id "cris" no matter when or how they are created. Take care not to put this code within the `$.ajax` call.

Adding the event handler within the handler for the ajax response means that a new event handler will be created every time that ajax call succeeds, potentially leading to a memory leak and/or having the click event occurring multiple times. If you want to do that, you can add a call to `$().off()` before binding your click handler:

```
$('#chris').off('click').click(...
```

But that just seems like an extra step considering delegation will always pick up the event.

Comment: Why is that better than `.click` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

event delegation approach will work... a good event handler could be the nearest static parent element

```
$('#people').on('click', 'button#cris', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('I CHANGE');
});
```

but if you bind the event just after `$("#people").append(peopleHTML);` this will work also with `$('#cris').click`. Ve you some console error based on undefined variable event??

Comment: thanks for the answer and i think your answer is better since you are calling the button #cris on the #people and not on the whole body